# Connection to a database with zendframework

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, zend-db

I'am trying to create my owne function to add data to my database with the zend framework. But I have a problem with the connection to the database.

PS: I don't wont to use the default function in the class Zend_Db_Table_Abstract, I wont to create my own function to access to my database.
I just want to use Zend_Db to do the connection.

here is my configuration:

APPLICATION.INI :

```
database.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
database.params.host = localhost
database.params.username = root
database.params.password = ''
database.params.dbname = user
```

INDEX.PHP :

```
// Chargement automatique de Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql, et instanciation.

$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', 'production');

$db = Zend_Db::factory($config->database->adapter,array(
  'host'      => $config->database->params->host, 
  'username'  => $config->database->params->username,
  'password'  => $config->database->params->password,
  'dbname'    => $config->database->params->dbname,
    )
);

// placons la connexion dans un registre global à l'application
$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
$registry->set('db', $db);

// en faire la connexion par defaut
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
Zend_Registry::set('dbAdapter', $db);
```

And my function is:

```
 public function SaveClient() {

   $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO user VALUES ('".$this->getid()."','".$this->getprenom()."','".$this->getnom()."','".$this->getnele()."','".   $this->getville()."')";
     }
```

And finally the Action:

```
 public function indexAction()
    {
       $user=new UserClass();
       $user->setid(2);
       $user->setnele(fevrier);
       $user->setnom(mhamdi);
       $user->setprenom(marwa);
       $user->setville(bizerte);

       $result=$user->SaveClient();

       $this->view->add_result =var_dump($result) ;
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem with the connection?  Are you getting an exception or specific error?  You are also very close to using the `table data gateway` and row data gateway patters without actually using them.  See [Inserting Data](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.insert) from Zend_Db_Table for better ways of doing your insert.  If you haven't you may want to check out the [Quickstart - Creating a model and dbtable](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html).

Comment: No i dont get error but i can't insert the information into the database ,So it probably due to the connection because the query is correct.

Comment: I'm sure I don't understand, but why is the factory connection in the index.php and not in the Bootstrap? In your application.ini shouldn't the db params be "resources.db" instead of "database"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `query()` function:

```
public function SaveClient() {

   $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO user VALUES ('".$this->getid()."','".$this->getprenom()."','".$this->getnom()."','".$this->getnele()."','".   $this->getville()."')";
   $dbAdapter->query($sqlInsert);          
}
```

where `$dbAdapter` is your Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract instance, (that is your $config->database->adapter)...
but this function, (as you can see) will not return anything.

But as  drew010 said, it would be better to use the `tabe data gateway` pattern..

Answer (score 0):

If you use native primary key sql query may be like this:

```
public function SaveClient() {

   $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO user VALUES (null,'".$this->getprenom()."','".$this->getnom()."','".$this->getnele()."','".   $this->getville()."')";
   $dbAdapter->query($sqlInsert);          
}
```